# How to initially set a value in ng-select?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have ng-select with list of values. If i click on selected value and click clear , need to set first option .Please help me how to sort it out .
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-wdcg5a?file=app/app.component.ts

```
<ng-select class="" [items]="assigneeStatus" name="status_filter_id"
           bindLabel="lookup_label" bindValue="com_lookup_id" placeholder="Assignee Status"
           [(ngModel)]="searchAssigneeObj.status_filter_id" [hideSelected]="true"
           #status_filter_id="ngModel">
    <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
        <span>{{item.lookup_label ||  'All'}}</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm"
                 let-index="index">
        <span>{{item.lookup_label || ''}}</span>
    </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

Comment: can you explain more ? the question is not clear

Comment: I have more values in ng-select dropdown. I need to set default option (first option) to the ng select . If i click the clear icon , need to set first option . How can i acheive ?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no basic way to achieve this natively in `ng-select`.

You can define callback of `(clear)` event and add your first item in the array to achieve that goal.

HTML:

```
<ng-select [items]="cities3"
           bindLabel="name"
           multiple = true
           placeholder="Select at least one city"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedCities"
           (clear)="clearSelect()">
  <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
    <b>{{item.name}}</b> is cool
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-index="index">
    <b>{{item.name}}</b>
  </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

TS:

```
export class AppComponent {
  selectedCities = [];
  cities3 = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Vilnius',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Kaunas',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Pavilnys',
    },
  ];

  constructor() {}

  addCustomUser = (term) => ({ id: term, name: term });

  public clearSelect() {
    this.selectedCities = [];
    this.selectedCities.push({
      id: 0,
      name: 'Vilnius',
    });
  }
}
```

See the codes:

`multiple: true` -> [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-2lawry?file=app/app.component.ts)

`multiple: false` -> [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-yy9psa?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Can you demonstrate here ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-wdcg5a?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: I forked your code and shared the modified in a link at the bottom of the answer. @Sanjana

Comment: notify me plz if it was useful. @Sanjana

Comment: Thankyou it was very helpful ! But it worked only for multi select. It doest work if its single select.

Comment: For single select you have to use selectedCities as an object not an array. Example: 'this.selectedCities = { id: 0, name: 'city'};'.

Comment: In that case you have to set multiple="false" as well

Comment: Can you help me where did i go wrong? https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-b5z5wa?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: I added a stackblitz for single select as well. @Sanjana

Comment: but try to solve these problems more by yourself. this is a brain excercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `clear` method.

in your component add below code :

```
public selectedCity;  

constructor() {
        this.selectedCity = [this.cities3[0]];
      }
```

then in the `ng-select` add `clear` event as below :

```
<ng-select 
     [items]="cities3"
     bindLabel="name"
     multiple = true
     placeholder="Select city"
     (clear)="resetCalculations();"
     [(ngModel)]="selectedCity">
            <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
                <b>{{item.name}}</b> is cool
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-index="index">
                <b>{{item.name}}</b>
            </ng-template>
  </ng-select>
```

and then register the handler as below :

```
 resetCalculations() {
    this.selectedCity = [this.cities3[0]];
  }
```

here is the working example  :  [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-onqlja?file=app/app.component.ts)